# Stop ticker in LWUIT radio button

Tags: java-me, radio-button, lwuit

I am new to Java-me and I am using LWUIT to display radio buttons. When I select a radio button its text starts moving or it start ticker. I would like to stop that.Does some one know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the method `setDefaultTickerEnable(false)` with your `Button`.

[Button LWUIT API](https://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Button.html)

Comment: Actually there is no setDefaultTickerEnable method. The problem started again

Comment: WHAT? Where don't you finde the method?

Comment: see the link you have provided. Button.() isn't providing the method

Comment: The method is inherited from Label. If make a search in the page you will find this method.

Comment: The method is static. So we have to use the class name as,  RadioButton.setDefaultTickerEnabled(false). You can also use it for combo box as ComboBox.setDefaultTickerEnabled(false). @jmunoz Sorry for the mistake.